# Unexpected behavior from ltrim in postgres

Tags: postgresql, string-manipulation, trim

```
select ltrim('Test Thing', 'Test ');
```

Expected: 'Thing'
Actual Result: 'hing'

Why does the 'T' in 'Test' match and trim the 'T' from 'Thing'?

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd parameter is the *list of characters* to trim, not a string as such.
[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) about `ltrim(string text [, characters text])`:

> Remove the longest string containing only characters from *characters*
>   (a space by default) from the start of *string*.

So this:

```
select ltrim('abc cab b ca foo', 'abc ');
```

... only leaves 'foo'.

---

To actually remove *one leading string* 'Test ':

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Test ThingTest ', '^Test ', '');
```

But to update a table, this is typically much more efficient:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col = right(col, -5)  --  right(col, length('Test ') * -1)
WHERE  col LIKE 'Test %';
```

Only touches relevant rows (important!), can use an index where appropriate (important if only few rows in a big table are affected) and the expression is cheaper, too. About that index:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860)